# pm2 override error_file and out_file

Tags: node.js, pm2

I want to use -e and -o flags with pm2 to customize logs.

I tried:

```
pm2 start index.js -e="err.log" -o="out.log"
pm2 start index.js -e "err.log" -o "out.log"
pm2 start index.js --error="err.log" --output="out.log"
pm2 start index.js --error "err.log" --output "out.log"
```

Have anyone tried this? Any of those options doesn't work for me.